# Rename buffy franchise tag to Buffyverse for more clarity

Tags: discussion, tags

[buffy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy) tag is a franchise tag but its name makes it sound like a character tag. I know it's an old famous tag but it's never too late to fix issues. [Buffyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffyverse) is a fan favorite term for the franchise and quite well known among the fans. I did discuss [it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31876324#31876324)  but to no avail. So bringing it here.

**Note:** It can be achieved without affecting the front page.

Comment: Can't wait for the [tag:harry-potter] -> potterverse proposal... :rolleyes:

Comment: This might have had traction if there was more than one work significantly used on the site with Buffy as a key word/character.  There really really isn't, and while your term might be well known by fans (I know it), fans aren't the only people asking questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR:

No, but rename [buffy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy) to [buffy-the-vampire-slayer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy-the-vampire-slayer), the proper full name of the franchise.

### Rationale

I don't think we need a character tag for Buffy herself.<sup>†</sup>

So the question now is, what tags *do* we need?

The Buffyverse consists of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, which has a movie, a TV series, a line of comics and a line of novels, and of *Angel*, which has a TV series and a line of comics.

So we have two tags for two TV series and their accompanying works. For questions spanning the entire Buffyverse, just add both.

### Rename

I think that we *could* rename [buffy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy) to the full title, [buffy-the-vampire-slayer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy-the-vampire-slayer), with [buffy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy) a synonym.

But that's a bit besides the point.

---

<sup>†: I know there's a certain high-rep user who is a big fan of the character, but I still don't think we need a character tag for her. Sorry, Richard.</sup>

Comment: As a relative noob, "buffy-the-vampire-slayer" seems to double up as both a character and a franchise tag in one, to me. So it's a good option.

Answer (score 4):

### Nope

Has there been a single instance where a user has reported confusion over the tag? Has there been any occurrrences of a user creating a new tag because they don't know how to use the old one? **Is there more likelihood that users will recreate the "Buffy" tag because they don't know what a Buffyverse is?**

This seems like a change that would make little or no difference to people's likely usage of the site and could potentially make people's lives microscopically harder.